# Sticky bar from within a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, sticky

So I have a parent container that is a flex-box.

In this container I have a child div (`.child-two`) that I want to stick out once it hits the header - 60 px from the top.

However, the `position: sticky` doesn't work if the parent container is a flex-box.

```
<div class="parent-container">
   <div class="child-one"></div>
   <div class="child-two"></div>
   <div class="child-three"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the css:

```
.parent-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    padding-top: 24px;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: baseline;
    align-content: baseline;
}

.child-two {
  position: sticky;
  top: 66px;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.child-one, .child-three {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this without getting rid of the `.parent-container` flex property?

**This is a bit of a pseudo/reduced code, because this is a part of much larger web application with many elements.**

Comment: You are missing a `"` in your parent div, not sure if thats just in your post or if its missing in the original code as well. Also if you would add your css code that would be helpfull

Comment: @aMJay Thanks, the quote was a typo in the question only. I've added some pastings from the css to reflect the parent/child stylesheet in the real world app. It's part of a much larger web app, this is all that should be needed for this. All the other elements on the page are unrelated.

Comment: it seems like your code is working, here is what your code looks like after I added some colors and dimensions to your divs so that they can be visible https://jsfiddle.net/sru8hy19/1/

Comment: Hmmm... perhaps it's a parent of the parent that's messing things up or another element "higher up the food chain". I'm not quite sure.... I'll need to investigate this further. Are there any specific CSS properties that I should look for that breaks `position: sticky` and would make it not stick?

Comment: You can read more on that here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of what you have described, it's hard to tell what exactly went wrong in your css without seeing it.

```css
div > div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px;
  border:solid 1px grey;
}

.parent-container{
  display:flex;
  height:1000px;
  padding-top:100px;
}

.child-two{
  position:sticky;
  top:60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
   <div class="child-one"></div>
   <div class="child-two"></div>
   <div class="child-three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! I've no clue why it's not working on my app though... *sigh*